How do I enable the "round ties to away" rounding mode in C++?
I am trying to perform floating point operations in C++17 with round-to-nearest, round-ties-to-away mode. Searching on cppreference.com I found that there are four rounding modes available, including round-to-nearest (FE_TONEAREST). However, I found no information about the tie-breaking rule for the FE_TONEAREST mode.
I found via experiments that, at least on GCC, the FE_TONEAREST mode is implemented using the round-ties-to-even rule. Is it possible to change the tie-breaking rule to round-ties-to-away? If yes, how do I do it? If no, is there a library that implements floating points with the round-ties-to-away rule?
Thanks in advance.

Doesn't std::round() do what you need?

Is the results of 1.0 + epsilon/2 equal to 1.0 or 1.0 + epsilon? I don't think std::round() controls that behavior.

Ah, you mean rounding in floating-point arithmetics, not rounding floating-point to integer. I think it is implementation-specific, and if floating-point arithmetics is implemented in hardware, it is limited by hardware capabilities. The only choise to use unsupported mode is to use software implementation.

I'm OK with that, do you know of any library that implements this?

Look for "Soft Float" for your target architecture.

@dimich actually IEEE754 regulates that and it's default is not rounding to nearest, for good reasons. In some cases there is hardware support to alter it. Thing is, THAT function and these macroses are irrelevant to operations

It's more or less a flaw in how  meaning of these gesetround arguments is stated impelementation-defined in relevant section, ISO C only states these macroses are defined if it supported, while nearest value defined for round in 7.12.9 Nearest integer functions of ISO C documentation.

The lround and llround functions round their argument to the nearest
integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of
the current rounding direction. If the rounded value is outside the
range of the return type, the numeric result is unspecified and a
domain error or range error may occur.

There is some circular self-referencing is observed now, because it was adopted from POSIX, but POSIX documentation currently refers to ISO C.
For FE_TONEAREST case nearbyint()/rint() supposed to operate in a way similar to round() prior to C23, half-case always away from zero. After that it's to nearest, ties to even, additional rounding modes are possible
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2319.htm

The IEEE754 standard requires the the round-to-nearest mode to use the round-ties-to-away rule by default for binary floats. Moreover the [C17][https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf] claims to support standard-compliant rounding modes. The [C23][https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3220.pdf] introduces the distinction between tie-breaking rules by explicitly stating that FE_TONEAREST uses round-ties-to-even, whereas the newly introduced macro FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO uses round-ties-to-away.

However, the C23 standard says that support for FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO is optional. My GCC compiler does not recognize the macro, so I suppose they decided not to support FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO.

@DanielTurizo both links do not work? Note, in older (at least) standards only rint, nearbyint()  respect rounding mode, other function had a variety of rules.  In IEEE754  if I remember right  round-ties-to-even is considered default mode, it fights accumulation bias but introduces another. Most consumer systems do not tolerate it as default.

Sorry about that.
C17: https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf
C23: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3220.pdf
